# Extract information from mysql db into html file

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on my first big project which is a site where people can buy hardware products. I've made a database where I have tables from each element and I have to extract this information to a html file. 
For example table **CPU** has defined rows "fullname(ex. intel core i7 6700)" "series(ex.i7 6700)" "manufacturer(ex.intel)" "socket" "price" "tehprocess" "linktoimage". I want to extract the information from **db** and to put it into my web page. 
Can you help me with some real life examples or maybe useful manual?

[Here is what I did as example but it is simple html and I want to perform it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Saw6U.png)

Comment: is your problem solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow this process :

First of all make a file named connection.php which will setup connection to your database which will contain only this code.

```
<?php
    $con= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","database_name");
?>
```

If you are not using localhost and your database is online hosted replace "root" with your username and " " with your password.

Now coming to the file where you need the data:

Include your connection.php at that start of this file to establish the connection. like this

```
<?php
  error_reporting(0);
  require_once("connection.php");
?>
```

Then you can code and your page in html and css and when you need the data extract it from the db like this:

```
<section class="top">
    <div class="wrapper">
    <?php
      $query = "SELECT * FROM CPU WHERE product_id='{$order_id}')";
      $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

      echo "<div class='sub-col'>
              <h2 class='headings' src='".$row['fullname']."'>
              <p>."($row['series']))."</p>
              <p>".$row['manufacturer']."</p>
              <p>".$row['socket']."</p>
              <p>".$row['price']."</p>
              <p>".$row['tehprocess']."</p>
              <img src='".$row['linktoimage']."'>
            </div>";
    ?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using php and mysql.

1. Create a connection to mysql database using php.
2. Run a select query.
3. Fetch its records and render them with your required html.
4. Close the connection.

[php-mysql-select](http://www.phpknowhow.com/mysql/php-mysql-select/)

Comment: As general I know the structure of what I have to do, but i had no practice yet and I'm looking for some good manual

Comment: The last line **php-mysql-select** contains a reference link in it.

Comment: yah, i saw it a little bit later)